# Jquery and frame

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with a iframe inside, so with Jquery I want to adjust the height of the frame so it does not appear the scrollbar of the page, but appears only the scrollbar for the frame...

I have also a header div(with toggle function applied to it) in this page so I have to calculate also this height(when it desappears and when it is visible)...

I have tested this code and it works only with Chrome.....

Here the code:

```
    var height_body = $('body').height();
    var height_header = $('#header').height(); 
    var height_logomenu = $('#logomenu').height(); 


    $('#frameconcessionaria').attr( 'height', height_body - height_header);

    $('#header').css({'display' : 'none'});

    $('body').css({'background-image' : 'none'});

    $('#logo').click(function() {

        if ($("#header").is(":hidden")) {
            $('#frameconcessionaria').attr( 'height', height_body - (height_header+height_logomenu));
            $("#header").slideDown("800",function() {
                //animation completed
                }   
            );
        } else{ 
            $("#header").slideUp("800",function() {
                $('#frameconcessionaria').attr( 'height', height_body - height_logomenu);
                }   
            );
        }
    });
```

and html:

```
 <body>

<div id="header"></div>
 <!-- IFRAME -->
<iframe src="<?php echo $src; ?>" id="frameconcessionaria" height="500px" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"> This page requires iframe - Questa pagina ha bisogno degli iframe</iframe>
<!-- END IFRAME -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Firebug? What's not working exactly?

Notes:
You can just use

```
$('#header').hide();
```

instead of

```
$('#header').css({'display' : 'none'});
```

You should also have this code

```
var resize_frame = function() {
    var height_body = $('body').height();
    var height_header = $('#header').height(); 
    var height_logomenu = $('#logomenu').height();
    $('#frameconcessionaria').attr( 'height', height_body - height_header);
}
```

in a function, and call it on window resize I think

```
$(window).resize(resize_frame)
```